# Tapestry - apply method to a value from a tml loop

Tags: java, tapestry

I found a similar post but what I´m asking is a bit different.

I have a table 'Room' in my database to store info about rooms. One of the elements in the table is price (float in MySQL).

I want to print all my rooms in tml with their info so first, I make a List of Room Objects. (with createQuery)

Now, in **tml**:

```
<t:loop source="rooms" value="room">
   ${room.price}
```

${room.price} prints one decimal, for example, 120.0.

Is it possible to pass that room.price to the Java page to remove the decimal a print it correctly?

Comment: I´m new with Tapestry so I tried an example I´ve seen here but I think it´s not correct.

${getNewValue(${room.precio})}

And doing a public getNewValue on java page.

Comment: You should include it then, and include what happens when you try it

Comment: It does not work, maybe someone could help.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I do not know if it´s the right way but I made:

tml

```
${getInt(room.precio)}
```

java

```
public int getDynamicFieldValue(double arg1) {
    return (int) arg1;
}
```

Another better option or better code?

Answer (score 0):

In the tml use ${roomPrice}

Then in the Java do something like this:

```
public String getRoomPrice() {
    return String.format("%.0f", room.getPrecio());
}
```

The variations are endless, including truncation with an integer, but I think this gives the basic idea: do the conversion in the Java class rather than in the tml file.

Comment: Thanks! Bob Harner, I´m goona try your code too. I´m new with tml so I´m a bit lost passing parameters between java and the tml...

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to create a new `Binding` prefix which you can use in your template file without having to add a method in each page class where you want the formatting.

You can define as many formatters as you want, which you then can use wherever in your project you want like the following:

```
${format:price=room.price}
```

Example code:

https://wiki.apache.org/tapestry/Tapestry5HowToAddMessageFormatBindingPrefix